# Deleting specific name from the list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to display a user entered names in a list. Each name has a delete button, when the delete button is clicked the name should be removed from the the list displayed. I'm able to create the list but the problem I face is in the deletion. Im using `removeChild()` to remove the specific name from list but Im getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined` so Im not able to find what is the mistake and also unable to proceed. I need help in deletion please help me. Thanks in advance :)

[Plunker Work](http://plnkr.co/edit/gLaKOyaRmbPXdsthfLpJ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="userName" id="nameOfuser" />
<button onclick="addNew()">Submit</button>
<ul id="nameList">

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function addNew(){
    var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
    var createList = document.createElement("li");    
    var pop = document.createTextNode(newUserName);
    createList.appendChild(pop);

    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    var closeText = document.createTextNode("Del");
    closeButton.appendChild(closeText);
    closeButton.setAttribute("id","deleteButton");
    closeButton.setAttribute("onclick","deleteFun()");
    document.body.appendChild(closeButton);
    if(newUserName == ''){
           alert("Error");
    }else{        document.getElementById("nameList").appendChild(createList).appendChild(closeButton);
        }
      }

    function deleteFun(){
      var fullList = document.getElementById("nameList").value;
      var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
      fullList.removeChild(newUserName);
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You've used `document.getElementById("nameList").value` instead of just `document.getElementById("nameList")`

Comment: I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addNew(){
    var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
    var createList = document.createElement("li");    
    var pop = document.createTextNode(newUserName);
    createList.appendChild(pop);

    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    var closeText = document.createTextNode("Del");
    closeButton.appendChild(closeText);
    closeButton.setAttribute("id","deleteButton");
    closeButton.setAttribute("onclick","deleteFun(this)");
    document.body.appendChild(closeButton);
    if(newUserName == ''){

    }else{
      document.getElementById("nameList").appendChild(createList).appendChild(closeButton);
    }
  }

function deleteFun(btnDelete){
 document.getElementById("nameList").removeChild(btnDelete.parentNode); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Code only answers are really frowned upon, try to explain why your code will do what the OP is asking for

Comment: Try above code, I have update same in below link
http://plnkr.co/edit/z0vo1esRpXFFIfT1vNgx?p=preview

Comment: No Krushna, edit your answer and explain what you are doing different from what the OP might be doing. Point out where his error was (I am not the asker)

Comment: function deleteFun(btnDelete){
 document.getElementById("nameList").removeChild(btnDelete.parentNode); 
}
I just took button element and removed its parent from list, where as the actual code is not working due to inappropriate use of DOM elements

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.
First, the error is caused because you've used `document.getElementById("nameList").value` instead of `document.getElementById("nameList")`.

Second, you are setting the same ID to all the delete buttons `closeButton.setAttribute("id","deleteButton");`

Third, if the input field is empty you're alerting the user but you still add a delete button to the `body` element.

I think this will do what you want:

```js
function addNew(){
    var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
    var createList = document.createElement("li");    
    var pop = document.createTextNode(newUserName);
    createList.appendChild(pop);

    var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
    var closeText = document.createTextNode("Del");
    closeButton.appendChild(closeText);
    closeButton.setAttribute("onclick","deleteFun()");
    if(newUserName == ''){
       alert("Error");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("nameList").appendChild(createList).appendChild(closeButton);
    }
}

function deleteFun(){
  var fullList = document.getElementById("nameList");
  fullList.removeChild(event.target.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="userName" id="nameOfuser" />
  <button onclick="addNew()">Submit</button>
  <ul id="nameList">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I've used `event.target.parentNode` to get the `li` parent element of the clicked "Del" button.

Another approach will be to use something like this:

```js
function addNew(){
    if(newUserName == ''){
       alert("Error");
    }else{
        var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
        var createList = document.createElement("li");    
        var pop = document.createTextNode(newUserName);
        createList.appendChild(pop);

        var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        var closeText = document.createTextNode("Del");
        closeButton.appendChild(closeText);
        closeButton.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("nameList").removeChild(createList);
        }
        document.getElementById("nameList").appendChild(createList).appendChild(closeButton);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Task 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="userName" id="nameOfuser" />
  <button onclick="addNew()">Submit</button>
  <ul id="nameList">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here, I think.

```
 function deleteFun(){
  var fullList = document.getElementById("nameList").value;
  var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
  fullList.removeChild("pop");
}
```

You re getting value from node element, you can not call removeChild on it. If you want to call remove child, you have to apply it to node element

Answer (score 0):

- Send "sender" data to `deleteFun` like this `deleteFun(this)`
- Inside `deleteFun` get the list `var fullList = document.getElementById("nameList");`
- Then call remove the sender's parentnode `fullList.removeChild(sender.parentNode);` which is the `li` item

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Task 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="userName" id="nameOfuser" />
  <button onclick="addNew()">Submit</button>
  <ul id="nameList">

  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addNew(){
      var newUserName = document.getElementById("nameOfuser").value;
      var createList = document.createElement("li");    
      var pop = document.createTextNode(newUserName);
      createList.appendChild(pop);

      var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
      var closeText = document.createTextNode("Del");
      closeButton.appendChild(closeText);
      closeButton.setAttribute("id","deleteButton");
      //send the element into deleteFun
      closeButton.setAttribute("onclick","deleteFun(this)");
      document.body.appendChild(closeButton);
      if(newUserName == ''){
             alert("Error");
      }else{        document.getElementById("nameList").appendChild(createList).appendChild(closeButton);
          }
        }

      function deleteFun(sender){
        var fullList = document.getElementById("nameList");
        //remove list item from the ul
        fullList.removeChild(sender.parentNode);
      }

      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
  ```